# Coding this pyramid pattern with user input and spaces in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm completely new to coding and my teacher is terrible at explaining things. I have no idea what's going on in the class, and I really need help with this!
I've made lots of pyramid patterns before, but this is one I can't figure out.

I know how to get user input too, but I just need help understanding why this won't work. He briefly explained how to code this problem to us, but it doesn't work no matter how many times I change and try it.

I have to create a pyramid using the number of lines the user inputs. So if the user entered 5, this is what it should look like:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

So the number of spaces on the first line is four, the second one has three spaces, and so on until you get to zero.

This is the code (which gives a completely inaccurate output):

```
System.out.print("\f");
System.out.println("Enter a valid number between 1 and 20."); 
int num = 0;
int counter = 1;
num = keyNum.nextInt();
for (int i = 1; i == num; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j == (num -= counter); j++)
    { 
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = 1; k == counter; k++)
    { 
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    counter++;
}
```

Please help! I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly right, but you are starting the loops from 1, but they really should be starting from 0, and the condition in the for loops shouldn't have `==` which just makes it run once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= (num - counter); j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println("");

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was something so minor. You helped a lot, I was stressing for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your teacher will accept this. But it is just a one liner for fun

```
int num = 20;
IntStream.range(0, num).forEach(i -> System.out.println(String.format("%" + num + "s", new String(new char[i+1]).replace("\0", "x"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty close mostly the for loop is wrong.

```
for(initialization;condition;increment)
```

the for loop only executes when the condition is true.  In your case the conditions don't really make sense. Try changing it.  also your counter and i are the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting coding exercise. You got it almost right anyway as others pointed out.
There are hundred ways to solve the problem.

Here is just a variation that saves a loop...

```
int lines=5;

for (int i=0; i<lines; i++) {
    for (int k=0; k<lines; k++) {
        System.out.print( (k < lines - i - 1) ? " " : "*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a single (explicit) loop:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        int expectedSpaces = num - i;
        String spaces = repeat(" ", expectedSpaces);
        String asterisks = repeat("*", i);
        System.out.println(spaces + asterisks);
    }
}

private static final String repeat(String toBeRepeated, int length) {
    return new String(new char[length]).replace("\0", toBeRepeated);
}
```

As mentioned elsewhere, loop variables such as `i` usually start at 0 since such variables can be used as an array/List index.  However, in this case there is no related array or List so sarting at 1 simplifies the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on something similar, this is what I did, you could give it a try. It takes a user input and displays spaces and "#"...

```
    int size = n;

   for (int i = 0; i <= size-1; i++){
       for(int j = size -1; j > i; j-){
            System.out.print(" ");
       }
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        System.out.println();
   }
```

The output would be:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```